# Joining two tables and selecting from the result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am trying out SQL and having trouble figuring out making queries when it comes to combining info from multi tables. Been using [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) but they don't seem to have similar reference to the question below. Was thinking of joining them as my codes below but still that doesn't answer the question. Appreciate any advice. Thanks.

> Question:
>
> Products(itemID, description, quantity, supplierID)
>
> Supplier(supplierID, name, address)
>
> A product can be supplied by more than one supplier. Write the SQL to
>   list the quantity of each product by each supplier.

```
SELECT Products.quanity, Supplier.name
FROM Products INNER JOIN Supplier
ON Products.supplierID = Supplier.supplierID;
```

Comment: I think you will also want to `SELECT` `Products.description` or `Products.itemID`, given the way the question is worded.

Comment: This should help you conceptualizing `JOIN`s: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: If a product can be supplied by many suppliers. I think you have a table to join Products and Suppliers. If you have it, please show it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `product` table does not have two rows for the same supplier and product, then your query is very close.  I would write it as:

```
SELECT p.description as ProductDescription, s.name as SupllierName, p.Quantity
FROM Products p INNER JOIN
     Supplier s
     ON p.supplierID = s.supplierID
ORDER BY p.description, p.Quantity desc;
```

Note the following:

- The use of tables aliases (the `p` and `s`) make the query more readable and are used for every column reference.
- The final result is explicitly order by product, with the largest quantity first.
- If there are multiple rows for a given product and supplier, then you will need aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `group by` here:

```
select itemId, supplierId, sum(quantity) from Products group by itemId, supplierId;
```

Comment: This grouping only affects the table Products. How does it combines with Supplier to obtain supplier name for me to list it out together with the quantity?

Comment: `select A.itemId, A.qnt, Suppliers.name from 
(select itemId, supplierId, sum(quantity) as qnt from Products group by itemId, supplierId) A, 
Suppliers
where A.supplierId = Suppliers.supplierId`